# How to multiply and check the field of newly inserted row

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to add new rows having 3 input field and check if multiplication of 2 field equals to third input field. But my problem is if I check the multiplication of first 2 input field, the result will effect second row and third row etc because they all have same id and user can add many rows.

How to check with different id or without effected.  my some code are as follows:

```js
        function addRow(elem,id) {
  var trElement = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tr);
  var a = tr.indexOf(trElement);
  var b = a+1; 
 
           var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
   var j, m;
   
           var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(a);
         var colCount = table.rows[b].cells.length;
           for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
           var newcell = row.insertCell(i);   
           newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[b].cells[i].innerHTML;    
             
     
     }
      }
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    
  </tr>
  
</table>

<input type="button" id="agri" value="Add Row"  onclick="addRow(this,id)" />
```

Thanks in **Advance**

Comment: Do you want to get first and second fields multiplication value to third field in a row right?

Comment: yes, i want to get it. but if i try to get and add second row it will effect second row because of same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it Help you ;
cheak result as :

```js
function addRow(elem,id) {
  var trElement = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tr);
  var a = tr.indexOf(trElement);
  var b = a+1; 
 
           var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
   var j, m;
   
           var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(a);
         var colCount = table.rows[b].cells.length;
           for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
           var newcell = row.insertCell(i);   
           newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[b].cells[i].innerHTML;    
             
     
     }
      }

function cheakMulti() {
  r = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) 
  {
   if(r[i].children[2].children[0].value==r[i].children[1].children[0].value*r[i].children[0].children[0].value)
     {
 r[i].children[2].children[0].style.backgroundColor="green";
 }
 else
 {
 r[i].children[2].children[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
 }

  }


}
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" /></td>
    
  </tr>
  
</table>

<input type="button" id="agri" value="Add Row"  onclick="addRow(this,id)" />

<input type="button" id="agri" value="Cheak"  onclick="cheakMulti(this,id)" />
```

Comment: wow, gr8. but if first or second field is empty then user can input third by them and need not to verify

Comment: I thnk it is more better if I can use onkeyup or onkeydown in second input and automatically display the result in third field

Comment: use onchange and cheak both input are not empty

Comment: I cnt do, will u plz write me the if condition for that ? I am very near to my answer